# Create inverted rounded arrow that can overlay image

Tags: javascript, css, svg

[image]

I'm looking for a way to create the inverted pointer as shown above. I've seen a million ways to do this but with straight edges and not with the curve I need.

Can it be done with CSS or would it need to be something like svg. I need transparency on the outside so I can do things like this and overlay images.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `I need transparency on the outside so I can do things like this and overlay images.` – is there a `not` missing at front or end?

Comment: Sorry Frank I don't understand your reply there. Could you elaborate please? @FrankNocke

Comment: @LuckyLikey Rounded border radiuses at the top corners of joined divs which is fine with solid colors but ideal when I need to overlay an image

Answer (score 3):

And idea is to simply use `border-radius` and `background-attachment:fixed` like below:

```css
body {
 background:pink;
}
.box {
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   width:50%;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069) center/cover fixed;
}
.box:before {
  left:0;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
}

.box:after {
  right:0;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Of course, the drawback is that the image will be fixed on scroll.

Comment: Thanks Termani, that could be a good basis. Think I might have issues with it being fixed but I'll see if I can work round that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add something like `z-index:-1` to the `::before` and `::after`, otherwise they will be on top of the content of the div.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tweak to @Temani's solution that just uses `background-size` and `background-position`.

```css
body {
 background:pink;
}
.box {
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   width:50%;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069);
   background-size: 200%;
}
.box:before {
  left:0;
  border-top-right-radius:20px;
  background-position: left center;
}

.box:after {
  right:0;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And if you want to go the SVG route, you could do something like this:

```css
body {
 background:pink;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <path id="notch" d="M -20,0 A 20,20 0 0 1 0,20 A 20,20 0 0 1 20,0 Z" fill="black"/>
      <mask id="notchMask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <use xlink:href="#notch" x="50%"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069"
           width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
           mask="url(#notchMask)"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

**Update:**

The previous CSS approach fails for long content.  Here's a new version that hopefully works for any size content.  It requires the addition of a couple of extra `<div>` elements.

It works in a similar way to before, with two half-width elements.  But in each half we embed a full-width `::before` element.  That way, the background image can be set to `cover`.  We just need to make sure that, for the right hand half, we use `right:0` so that the element with the background image is right-aligned. Meaning we see both halves of the image.

```css
body {
 background: pink;
}
.box {
  height: 1200px;  /* Simulate long content */
  position: relative;
}
.half {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.half::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069);
  background-size: cover;
}

.half:nth-child(2) {
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
}
.half:nth-child(2)::before {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="half"></div>
  <div class="half"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: oh, how come I didn't find this ??!! :p

Comment: Probably because you are cleverer than me. I only have a simple mind. ;)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau that looks very promising. I will put this into practise tomorrow am (UK time) and give you a tick if all good. Huge thanks to you sir!!

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks for your response here, much appreciated. It definitely 90% achieves what I want but there are a couple of issues i'm not sure of how to deal with: firstly, using background-size:200% means I can't use 'cover' to adapt to inner content. Any thoughts on this? Also, do you know how I can render the full size of the background image regardless of content. Thanks for your help, this is way more complex than I thought.

Comment: I've update my answer with a new approach that hopefully solves that problem for you.